# Matlab 3d-matrix

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have to create a very big 3D matrix (such as: `500000x60x60`). Is there any way to do this in matlab?

When I try

```
omega = zeros(500000,60,60,'single');
```

I get an `out-of-memory` error.

The sparse function is no option since it is only meant for 2D matrices. So is there any alternative to that for higher dimensional matrices?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please show us what you've done by editing your question.

Comment: Use the `sparse` command to create a sparse matrix

Comment: Please, describe why you could not create this matrix. Also, tell us if your matrix is sparse.

Comment: My matrix is sparse. But the point is, that I didn't find how to create a sparse matrix in matlab when the dimension is higher than 2.

Andrey, as I said before, my problem came from an "out-of-memory" error. It's the reason why, I can't create this matrix.

Comment: I think you are looking for a sparse tensor. Have a look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229154/matlab-sparse-tensor) .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Matlab only has support for sparse matrices (2D). For 3D tensors/arrays, you'll have to use a workaround. I can think of two:

1. linear indexing
2. cell arrays

### Linear indexing

You can create a sparse vector like so:

```
A = spalloc(500000*60*60, 1, 100);
```

where the last entry (`100`) refers to the amount of non-zeros eventually to be assigned to `A`. If you know this amount beforehand it makes memory usage for `A` more efficient. If you don't know it beforehand just use some number close to it, it'll still work, but `A` can consume more memory in the end than it strictly needs to.

Then you can refer to elements as if it is a 3D array like so:

```
A(sub2ind(size(A), i,j,k))
```

where `i`, `j` and `k` are the indices to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd dimension, respectively.

### Cell arrays

Create each 2D page in the 3D tensor/array as a cell array:

```
a = cellfun(@(x) spalloc(500000, 60, 100), cell(60,1), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

The same story goes for this last entry into `spalloc`. Then concatenate in 3D like so:

```
A = cat(3, a{:});
```

then you can refer to individual elements like so:

```
A{i,j,k}
```

where `i`, `j` and `k` are the indices to the 1st, 2nd and 3rd dimension, respectively.

Answer (score 6):

Since your matrix is sparse, try to use [ndsparse](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29832-n-dimensional-sparse-arrays) (N-dimensional sparse arrays FEX)