# How to create a sparse array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matlab 3d-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643279/matlab-3d-matrix)

There is a way to create a sparse matrix in matlab using the sparse command. But I would like to create a sparse *array*, a 3-dimensional array, is that possible?

I couldn't find anything about it, all that comes up is sparse matrices.

Comment: It is not currently possible. Some workarounds are suggested by Rody Oldenhuis at the SO question [matlab-3d-matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643279/matlab-3d-matrix), where nate also provides a link to a FEX submission that may help.

Comment: Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229154/matlab-sparse-tensor) is a possible duplicate